# Convolution of two compact support functions

Tags: distribution-theory, convolution

Let  $ \varphi$ a bump function with support $[-\frac {1}{2},\frac {1}{2}] $. and

$ \mathbf{1}_{[-\frac {1}{2},\frac {1}{2}]} (x) =\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }x \in [-\frac {1}{2},\frac {1}{2}] \\ 0 & \text{if }x \notin [-\frac {1}{2},\frac {1}{2}]. \end{cases}$

Let $f=\mathbf{1}_ {[-\frac {1}{2},\frac {1}{2}]}* \varphi $        (* convolution ).

Then Support of $f$ is $[-1, 1] $

Show that

$\frac{1}{f(0)} \displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x-n)=1$

Any hint.  Maybe I use *Dirac* **comb**

Comment: Shouldn't the support of $f$ be $[-1,1]$?

Comment: You're right.  An error from me

Answer (score 2):

Fix a point $x$ and look closely at $f(x-n)$:
\begin{align*} f(x-n) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \boldsymbol{1}_{[-1/2,1/2]}(x-n-t) \phi(t) \, dt \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \boldsymbol 1_{[x-n-1/2,x-n+1/2]}(t) \phi(t) \, dt \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \boldsymbol 1_{[x-n-1/2,x-n+1/2]}(t) \boldsymbol 1_{[-1/2,1/2]}(t) \phi(t) \, dt. \end{align*}

The intervals $\{[x-n-1/2,x-n+1/2]\}$ each have length $1$ and are thus nonoverlapping.  Consequently $$\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty  \boldsymbol 1_{[x-n-1/2,x-n+1/2]}(t) = 1$$ for almost all $t \in \mathbb R$. Apply an appropriate convergence theorem to determine
$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(x-n) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \boldsymbol 1_{[-1/2,1/2]}(t) \phi(t) \, dt$$
where
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \boldsymbol 1_{[-1/2,1/2]}(t) \phi(t) \, dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \boldsymbol 1_{[-1/2,1/2]}(-t) \phi(t) \, dt = f(0).
$$

Comment: Ooooh,  how to say thanks you? Very clear.  Thanks